# what is the best way to charge a capacitor bank from an SLA battery

Tags: batteries, capacitor, charging

I need to charge a capacitor bank of 25 2.5v 55 farrad capacitors from a 2v 200Ah gel cell SLA battery, and modify the discharge time so that it discharges at 150Ah. I was wondering what the most compact solution is that will not damage the battery or capacitor bank, as at around $200 each, I am not too keen on replacing them frequently.

sorry about the mistakes, and yes the battery could easily drive the motor but, the application is a single loop linear motor, which requires a high amp, pulsed input. my thought was that, seeing as a capacitor has a very low startup resistance, charging it directly from the battery may have the same effect as a short circuit. I also found that a resistor of 0.0135ohms with a tolerance of +/-1 percent will drop the current to a manageable 150 A, which is used as both the charging current and the discharge current, and there is an estimated min. voltage of about 2.5v.

Comment: Question needs tidying and a little more detail. Discharge is in A, not Ah. Caps are in parallel I assume. Do you mean caps discharge at 150A - if so into what? Or that battery charges caps at 150A. Or ... .  What is powered by the caps. What type of load. What minimum voltage. This looks easy enough [tm] with an exact spec of what is actually needed. Why use caps? Would not batteries be able to meet need? If not, why not? etc

Comment: Single loop linear motor = [railgun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Railgun)?

Comment: sort of but used as a star-post driver; I always get my finger with the mallet

Comment: When you need to add more information, please edit it into your original post, or add it as a comment to your question. Thanks.

Comment: Are you positive that your battery can provide 150A after all? - I tend to doubt that, and conclude that the internal resistance of the battery, the wiring, and such will by itself limit the current to way below those 150A.

Comment: Are you really doing all of this at 2V? 12 or 24V make more sense. Note that wires have a nonzero resistance!